# How to remove border of diagram when clicking it?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I searched the documentation of GoJS, but nothing was found. Is it possible?

Comment: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/HTMLInteraction.html#HTMLFocusOnDiagrams.  Not surprised you didn't find it but it is there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the outline from all HTML Canvas elements inside your Diagram div. Add this to your CSS:

```
#myDiagram canvas {
  outline: none;
}
```

Live example in GoJS:

http://codepen.io/simonsarris/pen/FviEw

Answer (score 0):

**go to page that your Diagram is drawing and after draw diagram write this code:**

```
$myDiagramDiv = $page.find("#myDiagramDiv");
$myDiagramDiv[0].childNodes[0].style.outline = "none";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).